# How to display tooltip on TitleBar

Tags: mfc

I have a child window derived from CMDIChildWndEx named as CTestTooltipMdiChildWnd, on CTestTooltipMdiChildWnd titlebar, I have drawn a custom icon which is initially disabled.
When user mouse over on this custom icon, I should get a tooltip displayed.

**I get rect value of custom icon.**

Any input how can I do this.Can anybody suggest any link where tutorial is available to understand.

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear to me, but if you know the rectangle of the custom icon, then you can use `CTooltipCtrl` and specify that bounding rectangle.